# Table second td is under first td (image)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a layout issue with tables here. I know this is not the best practice but it must be done like this.

So I have the following table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="/arte.jpg" alt=""/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong>Mira en Scheldeland</strong>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that second td is not at same height as the image.
Like this:

```
TD1
   TD2
```

I tried valign but this doesn't work.

Can I get any help?

Comment: td valign="top" is what you want or in style { vertical-align: top;}. set the line-height / padding to align the image and the text. you should maybe try vertical align to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valign should solve your problem here... Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ahrhq/

I tested it in IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome, Firefox ... otherwise give us some more info about your stylesheet(s)

Comment: Hi, i don't know why. valign doesn't work but if i do it with css (vetical-align) then it works... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

your image tag is not properly terminated:

```
<img src="/arte.jpg" />
```

Comment: This is not the question... but you're right. BWT, It's missing required `alt`  attribute.

Comment: Quite right; I misread OP, thought the td elements were not aligning horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of behaviour when floating is applied to the td

can you check with firebug, or similar, whether it's being applied float in the stylesheets?

There's definitely something up with the page's CSS.

Also check if you're missing the doctype.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text to be aligned top with the image just make sure there is no padding or that padding top/bottom is the same for both td tags.

Otherwise to have it both align middle just take off the valign values.

Lastly you could try to take off          < tbody >

Comment: my bad the tag didn't show. is there a reason you're using tables? it would be just as easy to use divs instead.

Comment: This is content of content management system, which is used by a non technical worker...